# How can you instantiate an instance of a type, already set to a specific value, if you only have the string representation of the type and the value?

Tags: c#, types, activator, createinstance

I have the following four strings; two pairs, each with a string representing of the value and it's data type.

```
string stringValueOfA = "Hello World!";
string stringTypeOfA  = "System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";

string stringValueOfB = "44";
string stringTypeOfB  = "System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
```

I know I can get the Types of each like so...

```
var typeOfA = Type.GetType(stringTypeOfA);
var typeOfB = Type.GetType(stringTypeOfB);
```

...and I can activate new instances of said types like this...

```
var a = Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfA);
var b = Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfB);
```

...but I'm not sure how to create instances that are set to the value encoded in its string representations `stringValueOfA` and `stringValueOfB`.

Whatever the solution, I'd also like to avoid boxing if possible. I don't think it is but I'm hoping I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many BCL types, including `String` and `Int32`, have associated *type converters* which can be used to convert strings to instances of those types and vice versa. If you're working with one of these types, then you can parse a string like this:

```
public static object ConvertFromString(string typeName, string value)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType(typeName, true);
    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
    return converter.ConvertFromString(value);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
object valueOfA = ConvertFromString(stringTypeOfA, stringValueOfA); // returns "Hello World!"
object valueOfB = ConvertFromString(stringTypeOfB, stringValueOfB); // returns 44 as an int
```

Note: Because the actual type isn't known at compile time, boxing of value types is unavoidable.

Comment: Bingo!  Yeah, from what I understand, this is what Parse is doing (or at least is similar to what it's doing) under the hood.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, in many cases the type converter just calls the associated type's static Parse method. The nice thing about type converters is that they give you a standardized, type agnostic, object-oriented way to perform string conversions.

Answer (score 1):

`Activator.CreateInstance`, Creates an instance of the type designated by the specified generic type parameter, using the parameterless constructor. You have to set the value after creating an instance.

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfA);
```

The CreateInstance() generic method is used by compilers to implement the instantiation of types specified by type parameters. Read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes, I know about the Activator.  That's easy.  You missed the second half of that sentence. "...create an instance of that Type *initialized to the parsed value of the string*"  Again, while yes, I can activate a new type, how do I initialize it with the value contained in the string when I don't have access to a Parse method?

Comment: @MarqueIV: You can't pass a value. It just create you an instance using empty constructor and then you have to set values specifically.

Comment: That doesn't make sense!  How can you set the value of an int?  The int *is* the value!  Activating a new int will give you an int with the value of zero, but if `stringValueOfA` is "3" then I need an int of 3. I can't assign 3 to zero.  Sure, I could store that zero in a variable, but then I'd need to assign '3' to that variable which would a) replace the one you created with the Activator, and b) goes full-circle in that it still doesn't get me the value of 3 from the string!  It looks like getting the TypeConverter for the type is the answer. The activator doesn't give you anything.